# Websocket on C++ and Javascript not responding

Tags: tcp, websocket, broadcasting

I want to have a simple broadcast C/C++ server that will receive client's messages and send them back to all other connected parts, including the sender. I have the following codes:

**Server-side (C++):**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/server.hpp>

typedef websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio> server;

using websocketpp::connection_hdl;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

class broadcast_server {
public:
    broadcast_server() {
        m_server.init_asio();

        m_server.set_open_handler(bind(&broadcast_server::on_open,this,::_1));
        m_server.set_close_handler(bind(&broadcast_server::on_close,this,::_1));
        m_server.set_message_handler(bind(&broadcast_server::on_message,this,::_1,::_2));
    }

    void on_open(connection_hdl hdl) {
        m_connections.insert(hdl);
    }

    void on_close(connection_hdl hdl) {
        m_connections.erase(hdl);
    }

    void on_message(connection_hdl hdl, server::message_ptr msg) {
        for (auto it : m_connections) {
            m_server.send(it,msg);
        }
    }

    void run(uint16_t port) {
        m_server.listen(port);
        m_server.start_accept();
        m_server.run();
    }
private:
    typedef std::set<connection_hdl,std::owner_less<connection_hdl>> con_list;

    server m_server;
    con_list m_connections;
};

int main() {
    broadcast_server server;
    server.run(xxxx);
}
```

**Client-side (Javascript):**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Websocket chat example</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    font: normal 0.9em arial, helvetica;
}

#log {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #7F9DB9;
    overflow: auto;
}

#msg {
    width: 400px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket;

    function init() {
        var host = "ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/echobot";
        try {
            socket = new WebSocket(host);
            log('WebSocket - status ' + socket.readyState);
            socket.onopen = function(msg) {
                log("Welcome - status " + this.readyState);
            };
            socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
                log("Received: " + msg.data);
            };
            socket.onclose = function(msg) {
                log("Disconnected - status " + this.readyState);
            };
        } catch (ex) {
            log(ex);
        }
        $("msg").focus();
    }

    function send() {
        var txt, msg;
        txt = $("msg");
        msg = txt.value;
        if (!msg) {
            alert("Message can not be empty");
            return;
        }
        txt.value = "";
        txt.focus();
        try {
            socket.send(msg);
            log('Sent: ' + msg);
        } catch (ex) {
            log(ex);
        }
    }
    function quit() {
        if (socket != null) {
            log("Goodbye!");
            socket.close();
            socket = null;
        }
    }

    function reconnect() {
        quit();
        init();
    }

    // Utilities
    function $(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    function log(msg) {
        $("log").innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
    }
    function onkey(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            send();
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <h3>WebSocket v2.00</h3>
    <div id="log"></div>
    <input id="msg" type="textbox" onkeypress="onkey(event)" />
    <button onclick="send()">Send</button>
    <button onclick="quit()">Quit</button>
    <button onclick="reconnect()">Reconnect</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The messages sent by the client reach the server perfectly and it outputs the following:

```
[2015-07-11 03:59:27] [frame_header] Dispatching write containing 1 message(s) containing 2 header bytes and 12 payload bytes
[2015-07-11 03:59:27] [frame_header] Header Bytes: 
[0] (2) 81 0C 

[2015-07-11 03:59:27] [frame_payload] Payload Bytes: 
[0] (12) [1] Test_message
```

Anyway, the client does not appear to receive anything from the broadcast server. The server can handle multiple connections perfectly, but simply the clients do not output its answers.

Comment: If you haven't already, make sure communication works, e.g. by using wireshark, a very fine network sniffing software.

Comment: Thank you, Müller. It's true, this is a issue on my NAT. I tried to connect to the HTML using my 4G internet and it worked perfect, but it does not work if I try to connect to myself using my WAN or LAN ip, although it works using simply "localhost".

Comment: Then this becomes off-topic for StackOverflow, as it is about administrating your NAT router correctly, or setting up your firewall permissively enough.